# Can one person have two votes to delete?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting, deleted-answers

The deleted answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12100/732 has four delete votes, but two of them are from the same person.

How did that happen?

Comment: [Three "delete" votes delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/161792), so don't worry that the post got deleted without the requisite number of "delete" votes. Why the software lists one of those twice I have no idea (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer).

Comment: The user whose vote is listed twice has reputation slightly above the benchmark that allows him to vote to delete an answer. I wonder whether that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the data, those two votes came in at the exact same time, so perhaps the user double-clicked on the delete link?

We generally protect against this, but in very rare cases it can still happen.

Comment: Anyone want to try reproducing the bug? If you something with two delete votes (and, of course, you think it should be deleted), try double-clicking, see what happens.

Comment: they'd have to also be very close to the NYC datacenter to get the requests in fast enough. The odds of this happening from, say, Australia, are nonexistent.

Comment: I was indeed in Brooklyn at the time.

Comment: @JeffAtwood reminds me of http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail.html