# How does one person have two undelete votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, deleted-answers

Similar to the [other question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/can-one-person-have-two-votes-to-delete) but this time the other way.

szmear somehow had two votes to undelete [his post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12806). How did that happen?

[image: (A screenshot showing a post undeleted by three votes: those of szmear, szmear, and avi.)]

Comment: I think this is the first bug fixed as a result of a report here on meta.J.SE. Well done, Shmuel Brill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uhm... oops. Nice catch.

When a user wants to undelete their own post, but this post was deleted by the community (as was the case here), their undelete vote isn't binding anymore (unlike if they had deleted it themselves). In other words, three undelete votes are necessary to undelete the post. This part was working fine.

However, the bug was that we allowed the user to cast as many undelete votes as they wanted – making the whole thing moot. They could actually have cast the third vote as well and thus have the post immediately undeleted.

This bug is fixed in the next build of the site. Thanks!